# Multilevel menu with highlight

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need some help.

I have a site (for example site1.ru) with a left menu.

Left menu has a set of hyperlinks: page1.htm, page2.htm etc. Links can be located within group of links.

```
<ul class="left_menu1">
    <li>Group of links 1
        <ul>
            <li><a href="site.ru/page1.htm">page 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="site.ru/page2.htm">page 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="site.ru/page3.htm">page 3</a></li>
        </ul>
    <li>Group of links 2
        ...
    </li>
    ...
    <li>just a link 1</li>
    <li>just a link 2</li>
</ul>
```

Group of links 1 is only open, when I locate on page1.htm page2.htm or page3.htm (and link must be bold).

When I locate on another webpage of site1.ru, Group of links 1 must be close (?minimized).

How can I do this ?

PS: sorry, It's a little bit complicated for me to write it in english, but I think you understand what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may want to look through the jquery-ui library first.  https://jqueryui.com/menu/  unless you want to experience create one from scratch.

Comment: You should post the javascript code (if any) that's driving the whole process...

Comment: That's not exactly what I want.

Comment: When you said "locate" did you meant "hover" over the menu item or actually load the "page2.html"?  If you meant the later, loading a page will replace your current page.  Or are you talking about building a single page web application?

Comment: holden, I have a very-very basic knowledge about javascript, I just don't know what I need to find :\

Comment: Leng, I want a menu something like this http://www.vipsystems.ru/catalog.html - left menu with gray items. Do I allow to post a links to another site ?

Comment: Leng, When I am _on_ a some random webpage of site1.ru (not page1.htm, not page2.htm, not page3.htm) group of links 1 must be close (minimized).

Comment: You can accomplish that kind of menu easily using jquery-ui accordion.  Also you can add a jquery-ui menu to each accordion item to make it multiple levels.  If you are new to web development, especially javascript, start with jquery ui is a good place to learn too.

Comment: Are you looking to do this on the server- or client-side? That is, will the navigation involve full-page refreshes?